# Entity Framework 4 POCO - Lazy + Eager Loading

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading, eager

I have the following DB structure (simplified version):

```
Comments - CommentId, UserId
Users - UserId
UserDetails - UserId, Address, Phone, etc.
```

I am using `EF 4` with `POCOs`. The `User` property of the `Comment` class is marked as `virtual` (to enable lazy loading for it). However, I want when the `User` property is loaded (lazy) also its `UserDetails` property to be loaded (the relation Users - UserDetails is 1:1). Is that possible? Can I specify it in some way? I want to make lazy + eager loading in some way..

Comment: So you're wanting to Lazy load a `User` data. But, when the `User` is lazy-loaded, you then want to make sure the `UserDetails` is also loaded at the same time?

Comment: I don't know how much you've simplified, but if the `User` and `UserDetails` tables are really 1:1 and not 1:0..1 or 0..1:0..1, you should be able to put the to tables together into one, and load everything lazy...

Comment: @Pure.Krome - yes.
@Tomas Lycken - well, my DB design is like this and I cannot change it (also I don't want to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. You *can*, however, turn multiple tables into a single entity using the [entity splitting](http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-entity-splitting/) technique. Sounds like that's what you're really after.

Comment: Ahh - good pickup @Craig :) It's sorta like a view without having to make a view ....